# My ruby code does not seem to be working

Tags: ruby

Hi everyone I am having some problems with my code. It is unable to be able to work when i add in the code below.

```
until result || input == "quit"
```

However when i remove the input for that line the code works perfectly okay.

```
input = gets.chomp
print "you just told me #{input}"
result = " "

until result || input == "quit"
  result = gets.chomp
  if result == "quit"
    puts "Alright Goodbye"
  else
    puts "I heard #{results}"
  end
end
```

Thank you so much for your help:)

Comment: `result = " "` evaluates to true, which is your problem with `until result || input == 'quit' .. end`

Answer (score 0):

tristan,
you should change `result = " "` to `result = gets.chomp` or remove `result = " "` and use `result = gets.chomp` inside your until statement.  Basically fix what Josh is mentioning in the comments

Answer (score 0):

There are several Errors in your script. I modified it so it is running:

```
puts "Say something:"
input = gets.chomp
puts "you just told me #{input}"

while input != "quit"
  puts "Say something:"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == "quit"
    puts "Alright Goodbye"
  else
    puts "I heard #{input}"
  end
end
```

- No need to have two separate variables (`result`, `input`) for user input, unless you need both of them
- You used `results` instead of `result`
- In ruby everything except `nil` and `false` is considered `true`. So `" "`, but also empty string `" "` will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean "until result OR input equal "quit" (either of them)"? 
If so, it's a classic rookie mistake. It needs to be written like this:

```
result == 'quit' || input == 'quit'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues here.

You're never defining something called `results`, only `result`. This will probably throw an error saying that `results` is undefined.

Also, result doesn't seem to add anything, as your program is only using the most recently input piece of information, I'd simplify it to just have one variable named `input`.

```
input = gets.chomp
print "you just told me #{input}"

until input == "quit"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == "quit"
    puts "Alright Goodbye"
  else
    puts "I heard #{input}"
  end
end
```

Also, the `until` block will move on to the end of your program when `input` equals 'quit', so you don't need to also check the same condition in your if block. You could just put the result of that condition after the until block.

```
input = gets.chomp
until input == "quit"
  puts "I heard #{input}"
  input = gets.chomp
end
puts "Alright, Goodbye!"
```

Basically, you're putting in far more code than you need for this one check.

I hope this helps. Keep learning to code, it's such a rewarding thing to do. :)